# Vim vim-javascript can't syntax

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, vim-syntax-highlighting

## Vim plugin

I've problem when install pangloss/vim-javascript plugin.

It can't show syntax highlight on .js file.

Include document ,if/else ,do while

I'm already try pangloss github and find else answer, but can't solve.

Here's my setting link https://github.com/ChiHsiang/oliver-vim

Please help me. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
syntax on
```

to your ~/.vimrc file and it should work rightaway.

Comment: It's already exist.I use syntax on or syntax enable .same it. thanks.

Comment: Your setup uses quite an older version of Vundle (Your plugins are still defined as `Bundle 'repo-name'` while the latest version uses `Plugin 'repo-name'`). How about recreating your .vimrc with latest plugins? Are you expieriencing any problems with other plugins?

Comment: half a day reading various plugin tutorials and published README docs and none have mentioned this as a requirement. Using vim 8 native plugin manager and vim-javascript, this worked for me.